# Is there a tactic to help resolving existential quantifiers in Coq?

Tags: coq

I am working on [Software Foundations Volume 1](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/index.html) on my own it is its 2019 version by the way, and I have reached to its lesson **Inductively Defined Propositions**, and there, for almost one month I have been stuck on an exercise **re_not_empty** expressed like this in Coq (the exercise itself begins at Fixpoint):

```
Inductive reg_exp {T : Type} : Type :=
  | EmptySet
  | EmptyStr
  | Char (t : T)
  | App (r1 r2 : reg_exp)
  | Union (r1 r2 : reg_exp)
  | Star (r : reg_exp).

Inductive exp_match {T} : list T → reg_exp → Prop :=
  | MEmpty : exp_match [] EmptyStr
  | MChar x : exp_match [x] (Char x)
  | MApp s1 re1 s2 re2 (H1 : exp_match s1 re1) (H2 : exp_match s2 re2) :
      exp_match (s1 ++ s2) (App re1 re2)
  | MUnionL s1 re1 re2 (H1 : exp_match s1 re1) :
      exp_match s1 (Union re1 re2)
  | MUnionR re1 s2 re2 (H2 : exp_match s2 re2) :
      exp_match s2 (Union re1 re2)
  | MStar0 re : exp_match [] (Star re)
  | MStarApp s1 s2 re (H1 : exp_match s1 re) (H2 : exp_match s2 (Star re)) :
      exp_match (s1 ++ s2) (Star re).

Notation "s =~ re" := (exp_match s re) (at level 80).

Fixpoint re_not_empty {T : Type} (re : @reg_exp T) : bool Admitted.

Lemma re_not_empty_correct : ∀T (re : @reg_exp T),
  (∃s, s =~ re) ↔ re_not_empty re = true.
Proof. Admitted.
```

Although I am obliged not to tell anything about solutions but to get help I have to say at least about Fixpoint that is defined like this:

```
Fixpoint re_not_empty {T : Type} (re : @reg_exp T) : bool :=
  match re with
  | EmptySet => false
  | EmptyStr | Char _ => true
  | App re1 re2 => re_not_empty re1 && re_not_empty re2
  | Union re1 re2 => re_not_empty re1 || re_not_empty re2
  | Star re => re_not_empty re
  end.
```

I could prove the backward case easily. For the forward case I stuck at `Star re` there is a `∃ s, s =~ Star re` in the evidences or context and a `∃ s', s' =~ re` in the goals. The most probable thing to pass it is using inversion on that evidence but how to tell Coq with destruct to put `s1 ++ s2` instead of `s` and put the results in the context instead of in the goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was similarly stuck on this problem. I believe your Fixpoint for Star re should just be true. In regular expressions, the empty string is always accepted under star.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but I'm very tired now. I will check it out tomorrow.

Comment: It worked but what about such tactics?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider changing your definition of `re_not_empty`.

My definition is shown below.

```
Fixpoint re_not_empty {T : Type} (re : @reg_exp T) : bool :=
  match re with
  | EmptySet => false
  | EmptyStr | Char _ => true
  | App re1 re2 => re_not_empty re1 && re_not_empty re2
  | Union re1 re2 => re_not_empty re1 || re_not_empty re2
  | Star re => true
  end.
```

According to my definition, the `s ~= Star re` situation can be proved easily.

But the problem is, why does `re_not_empty Star re` is always true? You can look up the definition of `exp_match`, then you will find that `forall re, [] =~ (Star re)`. So no matter what exactly `re` is, even it is `EmptySet`, there always be a `[]` to match it.

I was also stuck on this problem for a long time. Wish my answer can help you.